# bind_param concatenate with other characters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I parameterize the following query and keep the hash chars at `$dienste_id` ?

```
$sql = "UPDATE emails SET `emails_status` = 
CONCAT(emails_status, '#".$dienste_id."# ') WHERE `emails_id` = '".$emails_id."'";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Would the following work?

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "UPDATE emails SET emails_status = CONCAT(emails_status, '#', ?, '#') WHERE emails_id = ?;");
```

You bind `$dienste_id` to the first and `$emails_id` to the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work :/
I guess I have simply to escape it before and use the variables inside of the query.

Comment: @Crayl: Hm, this works when I do it at the mysql prompt. Have you tested that?